# Create new hasMany object with ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to try something relatively simple.

I have a Parent Model with an 'always' embedded hasMany child model. Now I want be able to create the Parent model, which includes the child model. I am able to create the parent-model like this:

```
var event = this.get('store').createRecord(App.Parent, { title: "test" });
```

or

```
App.Parent.createRecord({title: "test"});
```

(is there even any difference?)

When I now commit that model ember sends: `{title: "test, whatever: "whatever", child: []}`

How can I now fill this child array? I have tried numerous ways and nothing works, for example:

```
event.get('partners').pushObject(this.get('store').createRecord(App.Partner, { age: 22 }));
```

gives me a Uncaught RangeError exception.
Anyway, does anyone know a solution to this? Would be really helpful.